# Can't login to paypal sandbox business Account

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

From last 2 days i am not login in sandbox business account.I have create new one and set a new business account but same issue are occurred.

when i login with paypal sandbox business account with this linkhttps://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ with right creadential but after login it will redirect me to this link https://paypalmanager.sandbox.paypal.com/login.do and then https://paypalmanager.sandbox.paypal.com/ to do login again but same loop continue here

Please let me know if any required changes or setting required for login and setting.

before 2 days its working perfect .

Answer (score 0):

PayPal experienced issues related to Business Sandbox accounts with the Pro option enabled being unable to login over the last week. This issue has since been resolved. If you continue to have issues logging into your Sandbox test account I suggest contacting PayPal Customer Support directly.